# Not-null property references a null or transient value - OneToOne - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a One to One relationship of Publication with TCC, Article and Software Registration. I also have a relationship of Publication with Student. In the form if I save Publication separated it goes perfectly fine but if I try to do this while related with any of the One to One relationship i get the error mensage:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.codeweb.demo.model.Publication.acessDate
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy127.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy127.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy137.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.codeweb.demo.service.PublicationService.savePub(PublicationService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.codeweb.demo.controller.PublicationController.savedPub(PublicationController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Like everything in the entity Publication is null. I've been trying for weeks now to resolve it but I simple can't find a resolute answer for my case.

Student Model:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idStudent;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date beginDate;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Lob
    private String photo;
}
```

Publication Model:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Publication {
    
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPublica;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date publicationDate;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date acessDate;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String link;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "publicationStudent",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "publica_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    private Set<Student> studentPublication = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Tcc Model:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Tcc {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idTcc;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String degree;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String course;
    
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publica_id", referencedColumnName = "idPublica")
    private Publication publication;
}
```

Article Model:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idArticle;
    
    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String magazine;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer volume;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer numeration;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer initialPage;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer endPage;
    
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publica_id", referencedColumnName = "idPublica")
    private Publication publication;
}
```

Software Registration Model:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class SoftwareReg {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idReg;
    
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String editor;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer edition;
    
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publica_id", referencedColumnName = "idPublica")
    private Publication publication;
}
```

I've already tried to save in my services classes of the One to One relationship like the example in Tcc:

```
@Autowired
private TccRepository tccRepo;

@Autowired
private PublicacaoService pubServ;

public Tcc saveTcc(Tcc tcc) throws RelationTypeNotFoundException {
    Publication saved = pubServ.savePub(tcc.getPublication());
    Publication pub = pubServ.listId(saved.getIdPublica());
    tcc.setPublication(pub);

    return tccRepo.save(tcc);
}
```

To save in the setPublication function with a constructor that redirects to it:

```
public void setPublication(Publication publication) {
    this.publication = publication;
    Publication pb = new Publication(title, publicationDate, acessDate, link, studentPublication);
```

And many of this combination:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "publica_id")

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "publica_id")

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "publica_id", referencedColumnName = "idPublica")

@OneToOne
@MapsId
```

The end result would be something like this in Tcc example:

```
course: "course 1 example"
degree: "degree 1 example"
idTcc: null
publication:
    acessDate: "2004-02-03"
    idPublica: null
    link: "examplelink.com"
    publicationDate: "2004-02-03"
    studentPublication: [{idStudent: 1, nome: "Student 1", beginDate: "2005-04-05T00:00:00.000+00:00",…}]
    title: "title 1"
```

Comment: as important as your personal context is to you, it's irrelevant to the question and future readers, so edited to remove :)

Comment: "Like everything in the entity Publication is null": You should include some debugging information, including: the full stack trace of your error, your `Publication` constructor (or what generates it), and ideally debugger output showing the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I couldn't post the debugging information cause I might say that I still don't know how to use the debug from VScode. But thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem which was that the relationships Publication, Tcc, SoftwareReg and Article were with the same request mapping.
So I changed from `@RequestMapping("/registry-api/publication")` to a specific one in each class that had the OneToOne relationship.
That looked like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/registry-api/tcc")
@RequestMapping("/registry-api/soft-reg")
@RequestMapping("/registry-api/article")
```

This is a very basic idea that I overlooked.